# print html inside two foreach circles

Tags: php, html

I've been dealing with some calendar code for a while and i can't seem to find the way..

So, i have this calendar showing tours(Y), months(X) and the respective prices for each combination. Now what i need is to add additional column showing the durations in days of each tour. I did that, and it works fine but i also have to sort them and group by the number of days.

e.g First column (containing the name of the tours) starts by title : "1 day tours" and is followed by the tours whom's duration is 1 day. Than an other title: "2 days tours"..and so on.

To do that i had to create two embed 'foreach' circles. The main 'foreach'  displays the titles " X days tours",, than the embed 'foreach' displays the proper tours. 
Now my problem is how do i print out the html code???? 
here is the code:=>

```
    foreach($tour_durations as $d){ 

    **print "<tr><td colspan="4"><b>Tous of <?php echo $d;?> Days</b></td></tr>"**

    foreach($result->tour as $tour) {
                        if($tour->duration == $d){ ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <a href="<?php print $tour->tour_url_tracked; ?>"><?php print $tour->tour_name;?>
    </a></td>
    <?php 
print "<td><span class='month of'>".$tour->duration."</span></td>";?>
```

<= the enclosed by stars, is the problematic code..

What is the rights way to display it?? What's wrong??

I hope i was enought clear! :/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='4'><b>Tous of ".$d." Days</b></td></tr>";
```

instead of

```
print "<tr><td colspan="4"><b>Tous of <?php echo $d;?> Days</b></td></tr>"
```

should do it

Comment: Or, better, `"...Tous of $d Days..."`. You can directly specify variables inside double quotes.

Comment: Yes, it did took away the syntax error! Thank you for that! But what can you tell me about the logic?? Does it seems right to you? Can i put the 'echo' code there? it still won't group my tours by their duration :(... it shows one title per tour.. Any idea on that?!? i would appreciate a lot!!!

Comment: The syntax error was showing up because you were using `echo` inside `print` which cannot be done. `print` and `echo` do the same thing, but it is said that `echo` is quicker than `print`. In the above code I used only one single statement (either print or echo; in my case echo) to display the data in browser

Comment: Well, I personally think that `$d` is more readable thatn `".$d."`.